# Broken cluster caused by possible authentication issue

Tags: cloudera, hue

I have a three-nodes home Cloudera cluster for practicing which has been working fine until some day some changes were introduced without even noticing it, below is the error message:

> org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

The front-end error is in Hue I can't see any databases nor can I create a new one; It still shows me query history.

What should I do to narrow down the root cause?

Thank you, any clue is appreciated.

Comment: You say that some changes were introduced without even noticing it, but your title suggests that you have authentication issues. Do you get messages about failed login attempts? What are those authentication issues and why do you say they were introduced without you noticing them? Also, can you see which services/servers are trying to communicate and whether they are all running? Normally this happens when Hive Metastore is down and it might be down without you even noticing in the Cloudera Manager UI (the Hive service might still be green, but the Metastore instance isn't running).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check all the services of the cloudera manager in order to confirm whether services are all running properly or not. If only a few services have a problem/connection issues then you will be able to narrow down on the root cause. Your query is quite broad and difficult to suggest anything meaningful from the information provided.

Comment: In this case it is Hive, and I confirmed hive is running, I will find out more details though when I am back to that environment, thank you